DateTimeParseException for LocalDateTime object despite having the format mapped
I have a Java 8 application that has to accept any number of date and time formats from a user. Obviously that yields an exhaustive list, as there are many ways to write a date and time. For locale purposes, though, this is all US-formatted dates (and yes, I checked that the locale was indeed en_US).
However, what should be a simple date/time string has been causing a great deal of strife for me. Here is my code:
String dateString = // user generated thing

// Remove whitespace for simplicity's sake
dateString = dateString.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

// There are A LOT of formats here, but I only pasted a small number of them for
// simplicity's sake, including the format in question
DateTimeFormatterBuilder formatBuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[MM/dd/yyyy]" + "[MM/dd/yy]" +
            "[MM/dd/yyyyhh:mma]" + "[MM/dd/yyyyh:mma]" + "[MM-dd-yyyyhh:mma]"));

DateTimeFormatter formatter = formatBuilder
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .toFormatter();

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);

When entering the string "01/05/2024 03:41 pm" (which, with removing the whitespaces, converted to "01/05/202403:41pm") I ended up getting the error:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01/05/202403:41pm' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 8

I initially did not remove the whitespace, and had the formats accommodate the whitespace (i.e. I had "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"). This gave me the error:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01/05/2024 03:41 pm' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10

As you can see, I turned on case insensitive parsing, so the lowercase am/pm shouldn't be an issue. Besides, it fails upon index 8 (the second "2" in 2024) without spaces, and on index 10 (the first space) with spaces.
I thought perhaps with the number of formats I have (again, not all of them are shown here), perhaps there was too much ambiguity, so I tested it by only having the MM/dd/yyyy and "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" formats. (I needed the first MM/dd/yyyy for other dates). Unfortunately, this did not work either, so I have no idea what to do.

I think marking all patterns as optional isn't giving you what you want. Have you tried making a formatter for each pattern and then iteratively checking each one until it succeeds?

@Jeremy I have SO MANY FORMATS, which is the problem. For instance, what if the user has one digit for the month instead of two? Then I need to have both M/dd/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy, etc. What if they enter "December 21, 1970"? See I have to account for so many options.... If there was a way to condense all of it, that would be nice.

by the way, LocalDate.parse("12/21/2024",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy"))  works fine  (one letter pattern M and d can also match two digits) -- same valid for h (and, despite strange, m)

please also note from the javadoc of parseCaseInsensitive(): "Changes the parse style to be case insensitive for the remainder of the formatter" (emphasis added) there is no advantage to call it at the end, please consult the documentation for more details

Why does having "so many formats" stop you from creating multiple DateTimeFormatters? In any case you will need to list all the formats you want to parse.

@user85421 Thank you for the tips! I didn't realize that M/d/yyyy could work for two-digit days and months. I originally had MM/dd/yyyy and it broke when a single-digit month was submitted. In either case, my issue is solved now and my giant list of formats had been pared down significantly.

You don't need to remove the space that separates the date from the time,
otherwise you won't be able to distinguish MM/dd/yyyy from MM/dd/yyhh. You also cannot use ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, as it is intended for 24-hour format.
I suggest you test this code:
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("[MM/dd/yyyy][MM/dd/yy][MM-dd-yyyy]")
        .optionalStart()
        .appendPattern(" [h:mm a]")
        .optionalEnd()
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, 12)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);


Thank you!!! This solved my issue! I had been building off code from someone else and didnb't realize I could have these "optional Starts" and such.

Very fine. You don’t need both hh:mm a and h:mm a since the latter alone will also accept 2 digit clock hour. So just .appendPattern(" h:mm a"). Also I believe it will work without .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0), but this is subtle, so you may want to keep it there for readability’s sake.

@Anonymous yes, you are right

Actually instead of .optionalStart() and end you may do just .appendPattern("[MM/dd/yyyy][MM/dd/yy][MM-dd-yyyy][ h:mm a]") (with the square bracket before the space)..
